# Python. Kivy. ToDo List. Реализовать добавление задач

Tags: python, kivy

Делаю ToDo List на Kivy, моей задачей на данный момент является создание задач в layout'е  midsp, но я застрял на месте взятия текста из TextImput т.к. не знаю как это реализовывается. Был бы крайне благодарен за помощь

```
#python

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import button
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher


Window.size = (400, 800)
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class Text (TextInput):
    pass

class CloseBut(Button):
    def on_press (self):
        pass

class Quest (Popup):
    pass

class Plus (Button):
    def on_press (self): 
        pass

class Label (Button):
    pass


def open (self):
    q = Quest()
    q.open()

class DaysApp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.mainspase = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.topsp = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, 0.1))
        self.toplsp = BoxLayout()
        self.toprsp = BoxLayout(size_hint=(0.25, 1))

        self.midsp = BoxLayout()

        self.topsp.add_widget(self.toplsp)
        self.topsp.add_widget(self.toprsp)

        self.mainspase.add_widget(self.topsp)
        self.mainspase.add_widget(self.midsp)

        self.label = Label()
        self.plus = Plus()
        self.popup = Quest()
        self.text = Text()

        self.plus.bind(on_press = open)

        self.toplsp.add_widget(self.label)
        self.toprsp.add_widget(self.plus)

        return self.mainspase



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = DaysApp()
    app.run()
```

```
#:kivy 2.0

<Label>:
    text: "Days"
    background_normal: '2.png'
    background_down: '2.png'

<Plus>:
    text: "+"
    background_normal: '1.png'
    background_down: '2.png'

<CloseBut>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: 0, .75, .75, 1
    text: "Add"

<Text>:
    font_size: 16

<Quest>:
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: "Add task"
    title_color: [0,.75,.75,1]
    separator_color: [0,.75,.75,1]
    background: '0.png'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 350, 350
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        Text:
            size_hint: 1,1
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1,.1
        CloseBut:
            size_hint: 1,.2
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать self.txt1, self.lbl1, и др..

Вот пример

```
class MyApp(App):
# layout
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=10, orientation='vertical')
        btn1 = Button(text="OK")
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.buttonClicked)
        layout.add_widget(btn1)
        self.lbl1 = Label(text="test")
        layout.add_widget(self.lbl1)
        self.txt1 = TextInput(text='', multiline=False)
        layout.add_widget(self.txt1)
        return layout

# button click function
    def buttonClicked(self,btn):
        self.lbl1.text = "You wrote " + self.txt1.text

# run app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run() # join all items in a list into 1 big string
```

Использование

```
def buttonClicked(self,btn):
        lbl1.text = "You wrote " + txt1.text <- only exists in the build method
```